# Print out long IPv6 of an interface

Tags: ubuntu, centos, terminal, ipv6

Is there a command to print out the long IPv6 version (i.e. with all zeros instead of the short version with `::`) of an interface?

For example, `ip -6 addr -I eth0 full`

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
grep eth0 /proc/net/if_inet6 | cut -d' ' -f1
```

will give you the full adress in hexdecimal. You still have to insert the `:` separators if you want them. (You didn't say *why* you needed all zeroes - anything that needs `:` will also accept short forms with `::`).

**Edit**

For the prefix of a DNS PTR, something like

```
grep eth0 /proc/net/if_inet6 | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev | sed 's/./&./g'
```

Note that it will return *all* IPv6 addresses for this interface, so you need to iterate.

Also, if you need to set DNS PTR entries from existing IPv6 on interfaces, very likely something in the way you handle DNS is very wrong. Usually you do it the other way around: Whatever the source for your DNS entries is, that should also determine the address(es) on your interface(s).

Comment: I need the IPv6 address with all zeros to parse it into a DNS PTR record. PTR records need all zeros, must be seperated with dots and is written backwards.

Answer (score 2):

For generating reverse DNS records then maybe `sipcalc` is a better tool:

```
$ sipcalc -r 2001:db8::1
-[ipv6 : 2001:db8::1] - 0

[IPV6 DNS]
Reverse DNS (ip6.arpa)  -
1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.b.d.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa.
```

Just use `grep` to get the record name itself:

```
$ sipcalc -r 2001:db8::1 | fgrep .ip6.arpa
1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.b.d.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa.
```